# Finding exact string in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to read file using python and separate lines having 'Device 1' string it. Input will be given by user as to what he wants to find Device 1, Device 2 and so on. when I try to search line having 'Device 1', it finds all other lines having 'Device 11', 'Device 12' till 'Device 19'.
I am tryin to do it using regular expression. I also tried using for loop and in operator like; **for Device 1 in string** .. But it doesn't works.

Has anyone else faced same problem and is there any way to match exact string Device 1 and not Device 11.

To be more specific, I am trying to do something like this:

```
def device_status(line_num, dev_num):
    device_num = str(dev_num)
    device = 'Device ' + device_num
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for string in lines:
        if line_num in string:
            if re.search(device, string):
                print(string)
            else:
                continue
```

I have to append device number received with string 'Device'. when I pass device in re.search, I am not able to use it in raw string format as if I do so, it is not being interpreted correctly. Because of this I am not able to use any word boundaries also.

How should I do it in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you can't use word boundaries, but here is a solution with a negative lookahead (`?!`) that rules out digits (`\d`) after the device number you are currently looking for:

```
device = 'Device ' + device_num
pattern = device + "(?!\d)"
```

Trying that with a few examples gives you:

```
print(re.search(pattern, "Device 1 blabla"))
print(re.search(pattern, "Device 12 blabla"))
print(re.search(pattern, "Device 19blabla"))

# outputs
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='Device 1'>
# None
# None
```

Comment: I was trying to add boundaries directly in variable device, like re.search(r'device') which it was reading in raw format as device and number was getting excluded. But approach suggested by you works. 

Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You should use boundries with \bYou should use word boundries with `\b`, like example below:

```
\bDevice1\b
```

[Example](https://regexr.com/5q9hn)